# how use picasso in a recyclerview viewHolder?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso, android-viewholder

I'm trying to use Picasso in my project instead of using R.drawable, i'm trying to change the code, but i find difficult to use Picasso with my Viewholder, maybe you guys can help me and tell me how can i change my code to use Picasso.

java.class

```
public class RibeiraDePena_PT extends AppCompatActivity
{
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
Toolbar toolbar;
NavigationView navigationView;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter programAdapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutmanager;
//Indicar Titulo, descricao e imagem(mesmo tamanho)
String[] programTituloList =
        {
                "Ponte Romana / do Trajano","Praça de Camões"
        };
String[] programDescList =
        {
                "Descricao-Ponte",
                "Descricao-praça camoes     hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh"


        };
int [] programImages =
        {
                R.drawable.chaves_estelas,R.drawable.chaves_estelas
        };
String[] Url =
        {
                "https://www.google.com","https://www.google.com"
        };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ribeira_tr);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutmanager);
    programAdapter = new ProgramAdapter(this, programTituloList, programDescList, programImages, Url);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(programAdapter);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationview);
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationview);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar,
            R.string.navigration_open, R.string.navigration_close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
}
```

adpater.class

```
public class ProgramAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProgramAdapter.ViewHolder> {
Context context;
String[] programTituloList;
String[] programDescList;
String[] Url;
int[] programImages;

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView rowTitulo;
    TextView rowDesc;
    ImageView rowImage;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        rowTitulo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_titulo);
        rowDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_desc);
        rowImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagem_box);

    }
}

public ProgramAdapter(Context context, String[] programTituloList,
                      String[] programDescList, int[] images, String[] Url) {
    this.context = context;
    this.programTituloList = programTituloList;
    this.programDescList = programDescList;
    this.programImages = images;
    this.Url = Url;

}
@NonNull
@Override
public ProgramAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.box, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return programTituloList.length;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProgramAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.rowTitulo.setText(programTituloList[position]);
    holder.rowDesc.setText(programDescList[position]);
    holder.rowImage.setImageResource(programImages[position]);

    holder.rowImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(Url[holder.getBindingAdapterPosition()]));
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

I was successfully able to use Picasso outside a Viewholder.

Comment: Exactly what problem you are facing ? if you need `Context` each view has it . Just use `view.getContext()` .

Comment: for example do i take R.drawable.chaves_estelas and put the url link here?
how can i change that code for something like this?
img_X = findViewById(R.id.img_X);
        String imagemX = "https://www.encostasdenantes.com/imagens/chaves.jpg";
        Picasso.with(this).load(imagemX).fit().into(img_X);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `holder.rowImage.setImageResource(programImages[position]);` in onBindViewHolder with

```
Picasso.get().load(programImages[position]).into(holder.rowImage);
```

Comment: int[] programImages =
            {
                    R.drawable.image,
            }
and here i just put string and URL?

Comment: I checked this code and worked. do you check this?

Comment: yes it worked, many thanks, now i just need a way to use in animatedrawable

Comment: Ask the question clearly

Comment: sry, i'm trying to use Carousel view with picasso, i found this but is in kotlin
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-load-the-imageurl-to-carousel-view-like-e-commerce-app-using-picasso-in-k/